# Kextual Healing: How can I remove Kexts that appear on startup?

Tags: macos, terminal, kernel-extension

On my Mac I have a load of Kexts appearing that read like this (there are 14 or so):

```
The system extension "/System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext" was installed improperly and cannot be used...
```

Now they didn't start appearing after I consciously did anything, and I've read various threads about it elsewhere. I wonder if there is a programming solution here (using Terminal, perhaps) - something that will suppress the kexts? They mostly seem to relate to hp printer drivers, that sort of thing. Stuff I never use.

None of them seem to relate to things in my Login Items in System Preferences.

Comment: This question is off-topic and should be moved to apple.stackexchange.com as it pertains to OS X power user/configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which OS X version you're running. Since 10.10 Yosemite, third party kexts shouldn't be installed to /System/Library/Extensions/ but /Library/Extensions/ and need to be codesigned.

If you're really sure you don't need the kexts (or you know how to get them back) you can just delete them.

If you want to find out why they're considererd "installed improperly" you can instead run `kextutil -n` on them:

```
kextutil -n /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext
```

This should tell you whether the problem is signing, permissions or something else.

Comment: Thanks pmdj. Didn't realise the remit of the two forums was different! Thanks for your suggestion - I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi there. I did that and  got this:

    /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext - dependency 'com.apple.kernel.libkern' not found.
/System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext - dependency 'com.apple.kernel.libkern' not found.
Diagnostics for /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext:
Warnings: 
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done): 
        IJ170b...etc.

Ends like this: Kext has no executable or compatible version, so it should not declare any OSBundleLibraries.

Any idea why or what I need to do?

Comment: A dependency of "com.apple.kernel.libkern" indicates a really, really old kext. (modern ones use "com.apple.kpi.libkern") There's not much you can do other than delete the kext, and possibly install a new version of whatever product installed it, if necessary. (Sounds like a bunch of printer drivers.)